# Ubuntu 12.04: Unable to add or delete a user named 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, useradd

I am trying to install MySql on Ubuntu 12.04 but the installation is failing with the error: "*Can't change to run as user 'mysql'. Check if the user 'mysql' exits.*"

So I go ahead type in the command :
'*cat /etc/passwd | grep mysql*' 
and result is null.

I try to add a user 'mysql' by issuing the command 
'*useradd mysql*'. But it fails with the message:
'*useradd: user 'mysql' already exists*'.

When I try to  delete the user 'mysql' using the command 
'*userdel mysql*' it also fails with the message
"*userdel: cannot remove entry 'mysql' from /etc/passwd.*"

Can anyone explain me what's going on and suggest a solution.

Comment: What does the same grep on /etc/shadow say?

Comment: It is also null.

Comment: It may be you've just neglected to paste it in, but shouldn't you be running sudo before all of those commands?

Comment: I do prefix sudo to all commands concerned here.

Comment: Thought so :) .. to quote the site "As of Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5 is installed by default", seems odd you'd have to install it.

Comment: Re-installing Ubuntu would be the easiest thing to do. But I would like a solution that does not involve re-installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this problem might be because of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/988072) in Ubuntu, but I am not sure.
Anyways, I found a way to solve this problem.

I manually add group **mysql** by adding the following line to **/etc/group**:

```
mysql:x:1024:mysql
```

Similarly I manually add the user **mysql** by adding the following line to **/etc/passwd**:

```
mysql:x:1024:1024:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

Re-install MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

And that was it :).

Comment: check for a hidden lock file in /etc. That sometime break useradd/usermod etc commands without error emssage.